# Why won't Xcode finish a build?

Tags: xcode

I can have any kind of file open - `.swift`, `.storyboard`, you name it. My workspace just won't stop building. I've unchecked "Show live issues" in Xcode preferences, as well as "Show live issues for source code" in my workspace settings. My workspace has ground to a halt and what should be 20 minutes of work has taken 2 hours.

I'm using Xcode 8.1 beta 2. What's the deal?

Comment: Wait until this release is out of beta. :-)

Comment: Are you using a large dictionary by any chance?

Comment: Very strange. I'm on the same beta with no problems. I would suggest closing the workspace and opening a simple test project. Just create a new one based on one of Apple's templates and see if the same problem persists. Also this could be an installation issues in that the beta is somehow picking up code from a prior install and getting messed up. So if all projects are mis-behaving I would try completely uninstalling Xcode and reinstalling. Also clear out any Xcode settings from ~/Library as well.